# Event-driven architecture avoid getters

Tags: c#, design, object-oriented

I understand an event-driven architecture leads to decoupling.  However, can using an event-driven architecture lead to minimal "getter/accessor" use?  It seems that if you had some type of event handler such as BalanceChanged that passes the new Balance around then you wouldn't need a getter to access the Balance of an Account object.  Am I thinking about this incorrectly?

EXAMPLE:

```
public class Account
{
  public void MakeContribution(Contribution contribution)
  {
    contributions.Add(contribution);
    OnBalanceChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
  }

  private double calculateBalance()
  {
    double balance = 0;

    foreach (Contribution contribution in contributions)
      balance += contribution.Amount;

    return balance;
  }

  public event EventHandler BalanceChanged;

  protected virtual void OnBalanceChanged(EventArgs e)
  {
    // Create new AccountEventArgs with the calculated balance
    // Pass AccountEventArgs instead of EventArgs.Empty
    BalanceChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }

  private IList<Contribution> contributions = new List<Contribution();
}
```

And then inheriting EventArgs to add a `double Balance` attribute.  Or is passing data through event (messages) not a good idea?

Comment: The purpose of creating an event is not to eliminate a getter, it is to *provide notification.*  That you've attached the balance value to an event doesn't make it any less of a getter, you've merely made it a "push" getter rather than a "pull" getter.

Comment: But doesn't this lead to better decoupling because then I just use a Balance object (or double) instead of being coupled to an Account?

Comment: I suppose.  But you could do the same thing with, for example, a DependencyProperty in WPF, without using an event.  You could also do it with Reflection.

Comment: @RobertHarvey very true.  What I'm trying to avoid is coupling low in the object hierarchy.  For example, let's say a bank has a list of users that has a list of accounts that has a list of contributions and each has an amount attribute; this leads to: `bank.Users[id].Accounts[accountid].Contributions[cid].Balance` which severely violates the LoD and couples the client of Bank to the Contribution class.

Comment: Ah.  I see.  Well, that's a different problem.  A more sensible class design would solve your LOD problem without papering over the problem with events.  Events are just going to add more complexity to an already over-complicated design.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, recommendation to solve this?  I've read countless OO Analysis & Design books (to include DDD) and cannot wrap my mind how to solve this.

Comment: Your Account class is all you need to get a balance, in which case it becomes `theAccount.Balance`.  You're suffering from LOD violations *because* of all of the tight coupling you're creating.  If you need an association to a User, put a `userID` member in your Account class.  If you need a collection of contributions, make it a member of Account, as in `List<Contribution> contributions`.

Comment: Also, note that you don't have to write `bank.Users[id].Accounts[accountid].Contributions[cid].Balanc‌​e`,  you can write `var user = Users.GetUser(id); var account = Accounts.GetAccount(user); var balance = account.GetBalance();` or something similar.  Voila, no more LOD violations.

Comment: Did you get what you needed from our discussion?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Appreciate all of your input!

Comment: @RobertHarvey Whether you write a call-chain in one statement or multiple ones does not change the fact that you are violating LoD. https://javadevguy.wordpress.com/2017/05/14/the-genius-of-the-law-of-demeter/ Basically every time you have a getter, you are probably violating the LoD somewhere.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam: The code example in my comments requires a class redesign.  To be honest, I don't pay much attention to LOD.  Since I write sensible class designs, I seldom have violations, and if I do have one it is intentional.

Comment: Programming is one area where it is OK to break the Law, if it is intentional.

Comment: Unless I’m misunderstanding, your event-driven program would raise events describing the actions happening in your application (and persist updates to storage), but you’d then need _read models_ to retrieve that data from storage, such as an account’s balance.

Comment: @Martin Bean, that’s semi-correct. I wouldn’t even say storage. Let’s say I have other objects like Audit, Tax, etc., these then would get the Balance via the Event and then do what it needs to do with the Balance such as log it (audit class), or recompute the [income] Tax. But maybe I need to redesign my class hierarchy.

Comment: What I’m trying to avoid is a very deep object hierarchy (not inheritance hierarchy) via composition (not inheritance). I believe deep composition hierarchies lead to more violations of the LoD and therefore lead to higher coupling.